# Layout of woocommerce pages

Tags: css, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce on my website ,
The problem is : Both woocommerce pages ( Shop & My Account ) Use same css clas 
<`div class="main col-lg-9 col-md-8" role="main">`
When i change the width of my account page, Same happens with the shop page?
i spent Hours on firebug but couldnt figure out 
My Website : http://cardmart.tk

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parent element class to distinguish between those two pages.

Eg.

```
body.page-id-749 .main .col-lg-9 .col-md-8{ }
```

and

```
body.post-type-archive-product .main .col-lg-9 .col-md-8{ }
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hey,  Sorry code is not working  ,  i think it should be col-md-12 , 
I replaced it with 8 but still not workin , Though i found this code working `.woocommerce-account .contentclass .col-md-12{width: 340px!important;}`
Its working but i got a new problem , when i customize my account page , same changes happens on login page , like if i add word "Welcome" to my account page , same appears on login page? Can u help?